# How to get the token from cURL?

Tags: curl, spring-security, jwt

I'm using Spring Security JWT and I want to get the token with cURL:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> login(@RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String password,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    String token = null;
    AppUser appUser = appUserRepository.findOneByUsername(username);
    Map<String, Object> tokenMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    if (appUser != null && appUser.getPassword().equals(password)) {
        token = Jwts.builder().setSubject(username).claim("roles", appUser.getRoles()).setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, "secretkey").compact();
        tokenMap.put("token", token);
        tokenMap.put("user", appUser);
        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(tokenMap, HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        tokenMap.put("token", null);
        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(tokenMap, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
}
```

I try with this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" localhost:8080/authenticate -d '{"username": "admin","password":"admin"}'
```

and I get this error:

> Required String parameter 'username'

Answer (score 1):

Your request is missing the `username` and `password` params, you should send them with param `data`, not JSON:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/authenticate --data "username=admin&password=admin"
```

If you are using the basic authentication, you can use `curl -u username:password xxx`.

Comment: when i'm using this curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/authenticate --data "username=admin&password=admin"  it returns {"token":null}